# Shortest path to Tychonoff?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, product-space

What's the "shortest path" to Tychonoff's theorem (the product of compact spaces is compact)?

Of course, I don't expect that anyone will spell this out.  I'm just looking for a sketch of the main stages along the way.  I can then "connect the dots".

By "shortest path" I mean the quickest, most direct path to a proof of Tychonoff's theorem for someone who knows the basics of set theory (unions, intersections, complements, Cartesian products, projections), knows what a topology is (open and closed sets, bases, and subbases), and has the requisite mathematical acumen.

I have looked at various textbooks on general topology for this, but in all of them Tychonoff's theorem is positioned as a pinnacle of sorts, and I even get the impression that the authors use the "long march" towards this theorem as an expository device to introduce a lot of machinery, much of which gets used, of course, in the theorem's eventual proof.  I'm hoping that a more direct proof is possible if one doesn't have such an agenda.

Comment: Shortest path is to assume the Tychonoff theorem, of course! :-)

Comment: @kjo: A nice proof is given in _Principles of Harmonic Analysis_ (Deitmar, Echterhoff), First Edition, Theorem A.7.2, p. 273. The proof is a bit different in the Second Edition.

Answer (score 10):

For someone who has not previously been exposed to filters, probably the shortest path is by way of the [Alexander subbase theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subbase#Alexander_subbase_theorem); the link gives both a fairly complete sketch of the proof of this theorem and the very easy proof from it of the Tikhonov product theorem.

Answer (score 6):

I very much like sequences as main tools in metric spaces. I thus like nets as main tools in topology. The American Mathematical Monthly published Paul R. Chernoff's  "A Simple Proof of Tychonoff's Theorem Via Nets" ([jstor](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2324485)). In less than two pages the basic ingredients are presented and the theorem proved.

Comment: i haven't read that. Does it use Kelley's theorem on universal nets (which is itself a bit on the tricky side)?

Comment: no, Chernoff's proof does not use universal nets.

Comment: But the basic ingredients are presented without proof...

Answer (score 3):

I just scanned for you two sheets ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjvX0.gif), [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGTIu.gif))
of a small book “Combinatorics of Numbers” by Ihor Protasov. 
Here you can go from the definition of a topological space to the proof of Tychonov Theorem. The proof is based on the notion of an ultrafilter.

Comment: The links seem to be dead. (Perhaps they would last longer if they were embedded as images.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Thanks. I corrected the links.

Answer (score 2):

My favourite one is the one which uses the fact that: *A space is compact if every net has convergent subnet* - If you feel comfortable with nets, try the proof suggested by  Ittay Weiss.

Otherwise, the standard proof which uses Zorn's Lemma for a maximal cover without finite subcover is not that bad after all.